# Octave - Call to m file and variables

Tags: function, callback, octave

**I have condition.m, and it has inside it a loop that calculates the condition number of a user asked matrix:**

```
if(p == 1)
for i = 1:co
for j = 1:li
    somacolunas(j) = somacolunas(j) + A(j,i);
end
end

for i = 1:co
for j = 1:li
    somacolunasinvA(j) = somacolunasinvA(j) + abs(invA)(j,i);
end
end

% encontrar o valor máximo

maxco = somacolunas(1);

for i = 1:length(somacolunas)
 if somacolunas(i) > maxco
    maxco = somacolunas(i);
 end
end

maxcoinv = somacolunasinvA(1);

for y = 1:length(somacolunasinvA)
 if somacolunasinvA(y) > maxcoinv
    maxcoinv = somacolunasinvA(y);
 end
end

printf('o número de condição segundo a norma 1 é: %3.2f\n', maxco * maxcoinv);
```

I want to call the condition.m file inside another m.file (that is in the same directory) and make use of the output vars (maxco and maxcoinv) to do some other math.

**I know that i can do condition; inside the other m file to access the condition.m file. But how to get access to it's variables, and if i need pass values to condition.m for loop iterate?**

**Any ideas for the best method?**

Comment: Have you read Octave's [function definition documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Defining-Functions.html)?

Comment: Yes... It can be like: function [a,b] = (x,y,z), where the return values are a and b , and the input are x,y,z

Comment: So this question is resolved?